# Calculate a differenciation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, martingales, stochastic-integrals

$$a>0,$$ $$b>0,$$ $$\sigma >0$$
$X$ is the solution of : 
$$dX_t=aX_t(b-X_t)\,dt+\sigma X_t \, dB_t,\quad X_{0}=1 $$
I have also shown before that $$L_t=e^{(ab-\sigma^2/2)t+\sigma B_t}$$

Now we have $$Y_t=L_t/X_t$$
and  I have to calculate $$dY_{t} $$
Is it correct to write that : 
 $$dY_t =(dL_t X_t-dX_t L_t)/X_t^2\text{ ??} $$

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Where are the second derivative terms in Itö's formula?

Comment: Yeah, thank you even if it's late the professor told me that for derivating one processus stachastic we must  always applicate itô's formula. So it's false what I wrote.
Thank you again

Answer (score 2):

Since $L_t$ is a.s. positive and the function $f(x) = 1/x$ is $C^2$ on $(0,\infty)$ you can use Ito as you want to. You have messed up the algebra though. There should definitely be an $L^2$ on the bottom, not an $X^2$.

With your edited post you need to be more careful. You need to show that $X_t$ is a.s. positive if you want to apply Ito like you usually would.

Comment: I edite my post,

Comment: Ok thank you, you are right I forgot to mention that X is >0 (given by the exercice)